# Batch file not working in iis6 window2003

Tags: batch-file, asp-classic, openssl

I want to run a batch file that will call openssl.exe to verify signature and after successful verification it will unzip the ziped file. The batch file is working fine manually, but when I call it from classic asp page it is not getting executed.

I have tried everything but it's not executing; it not even showing any message. I'm using a 32bit OS.

Answer (score 0):

Add "Read and execute" permission for files CMD.EXE, OpenSSL.EXE for the user that running your Application pool.

Comment: Actually I tried to run a batch file that copy a text file from one location to another it's working fine but this batch file is not working

Comment: can you provide copy of your BAT file?

Comment: perhaps you should also add WRITE permission to your "Output" folder -- where you trying to store output file. and of course READ permission for "Source" folder -- where source file(s) located.

Comment: also, will be very nice, if you going to start handling 500 and 500100 errors to get detailed information about error

Comment: There is no error coming the page run fine but no work is done by batch file

Comment: This is my command i m trying to run through batch file c:\test\bin\openssl.exe smime - verify -in filename.sig -inform DER -content filename.zip -signer certificate.cer -noverify - out output.txt

Comment: add Read & Execute and Write permission for your IIS/Web application user to folder C:\Test\Bin\